# TokenMismatchException in Laravel 5.3 form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, csrf, laravel-5.3

I feel ashamed asking this question as it has been asked many times by other people, however I cannot find any solution for myself.

I am using Laravel 5.3 and I created a simple form according to documentation and other stackoverflow topics.

Everything works fine in my local machine. After putting my project on server this error keeps showing up after I submit the form:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

Added CSRF token in `head` section:

```
<head>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</head>
```

Form also contains csrf:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/save_new_order">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       <input type="text" name="web_name"> 
       <textarea cols="30" rows="15" name="web_description"></textarea>                  
       <input type="email" name="web_email"> 
       <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="WYŚLIJ" name="submit">
    </form>
```

I also tried using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

instead of:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Tokens are being saved in storage/framework/sessions/ everytime I use the form.

Please help me on this, I am working for over 15 hours and nothing so far.

Answer (score 3):

I had invisible BOM character in my `.env` file.

I converted it to utf8-without-BOM in my notepad++ and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

When it works on your local machine, but not on your live server, this could be a permission problem. Check Laravel's session directory and verify that you web-server user has rw rights.

Also, when you are using the same domain for your local and production server, try to clear your cookies. But you might have tried this already

Comment: It is just a basic hosting. I do not have any access to console or anything. Yea, I deleted the cookies already.

Comment: Ah, alright. Have you checked your .env file on validity?

Comment: I checked all config files and env file like thousand times already, but I am not sure what should I be looking for actually. Everything seems correct.

Comment: Well, it should be the same like on local :)
Which session driver do you use?

Comment: Yea all the configs are similar to local. I just changed the domain name from local to the real one in `config/app` and db name/password in `config/database`. The session driver is set to `file`.

Comment: Alright. Another thing: check your `config/session` file for some misconfiguration (other domain then your production one set e.g.)

Comment: And: Does the `storage/framework/sessions/` folder already exists on your live server?

Comment: The `config/session` file looks like I dont need to change there anything. Default settings are correct I think. Yes, the `storage/framework/sessions/` exists and its already containing some stored tokens and it keeps saving new ones.

Comment: Alright, thats good. Another common mistake is that you haven't set the right page domain in your .env file. Check that please!

Comment: You can also try to delete every file inside `storage/framework/sessions/` (but not the folder itself) and try to post the form again.

Comment: I checked both many many times. Unfortunately, it doesnt seem to be the problem

Comment: What browser do you use? Have you modified anything inside Laravel? A fresh project or are you upgrading an old (4.X) one?

Comment: It is a fresh project, nothing modified I am not that advanced. I am using Chrome but also tested on Firefox. What is interesting I have another website on the same Laravel version and I have it on the same server - it works. But this one not. Everything is configured the same way. hmmm...

Comment: This is indeed interesting! rename your cookie in `config/session` to something else and try again!

Comment: My password to database contains semicolon `;` because the hosting system generated it this way. Is it possible that it breaks the `.env` file cutting off the rest of the config lines?

Comment: @divHelper11 Doubt it. It's line-based. Try the approach I wrote in my last comment :)

Comment: I just renamed it from `laravel_session` to `laravel_session_new` but nothing changes. I dont understand why they keep making laravel so difficult ehh

Comment: Weird.. normally this is no problem. You can disable CSRF, but this makes your site more unsafe.

Comment: I think I will until I find some solution. Thank you for helping

Comment: No problem! Hope you'll find the reason one day

Comment: Hii , I know its an old ticket but I have the same problem and tried everything but still no way to resolve. Has anyone found the solution?